# Efficiency of firebase queue when dealing with small simple tasks

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-queue

I am trying to use firebase queue to create several workers to filter dirty words in my chat App.
But I read the blog and found out that firebase queue will first store the data in firebase queue and then pick up the words to filter. Like the following code refer to this [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/05/introducing-firebase-queue_97.html).

```
    var Queue = require('firebase-queue'),
    Firebase = require('firebase');

var queueRef = new Firebase('https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/queue');
var queue = new Queue(queueRef, function(data, progress, resolve, reject) {
  // Read and process task data
  console.log(data);

  // Update the progress state of the task
  setTimeout(function() {
    progress(50);
  }, 500);

  // Finish the job asynchronously
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve();
  }, 1000);
});
```

**My question**

When dealing with lots of simple tasks(filter dirty words) using several servers.
 There are 2 ways:

1. Use firebase queue, several queue server listen to firebase /queue/tasks
2. Use load balance to distribute the filter works to several servers without using Firebase queue

which one is more efficiency？ Is Firebase queue better while dealing with complex tasks？